# Oath2 + spring + jwt

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth, authorization, jwt

What I want to achieve:

- An Oauth2 server in spring with java configuration
- Login page on the Oauth2 server
- A user that accesses the client will be redirected to the login page on the Oauth2 server
- After login he is automatically redirected to /oauth/authorize for the authentication code (JWT-token)
- Afterwards he is redirected back to the client
- The client will get the access token from oauth/token (JWT-token)

Right now, I have the login page, and the use can be verified (DB check). 
Oauth is configured, but every path redirects to this login page (even if he already logged in)

My WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Autowired
MyUserDetailsService userService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userService);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        //.antMatcher("/**")
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("oauth/authorize").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("oauth/token").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .and()
            .csrf()
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");




    // This works for basic authentication: 
    /* http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
        .and().csrf()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");*/
}
```

My AuthorizationServerConfiguration:

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration;

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    return new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("isAnonymous() || hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .checkTokenAccess("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')");
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager())
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
}


@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("some-client")
            .secret("some-client")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "password", "implicit") //enabled all for testing
            .scopes("read", "trust")
            .redirectUris("http://anywhere?key=value");
}


@Autowired
public void setAuthenticationConfiguration(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) {
    this.authenticationConfiguration = authenticationConfiguration;
}
```

When I try to access /oauth/authorize, i get redirected to the login page, but after login, I just get redirected to the login page again. Altough the correct user was verified in the database... Any help?

Comment: After successful login, you would have a functional `JWT` token. Did you pass that token in `Authorization` header of next requests?

Comment: After successful login, I end up on the login page again. Do I need to write the response of the login myself and construct this JWT token? I thought the JWT-tokens were only for the Oauth flow (not for the login on the Oauth server)

Comment: After you've got the successful login response, extract the `access_token` field value from JSON and attach that token in your requests in `Authorization` header in `bearer <access_token>` format. Otherwise, spring security would consider the request as un-authenticated and redirects you to the login page again.

Comment: There is a Cookie:JSESSIONID and after successful logging in, I can access a controller like e.g. `.antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")`. So I am authenticated on the server.
But when I access oauth/authorize, the server responds with the content of the login page. Although there is also a rule: `.antMatchers("/oauth/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")`

Comment: Could it be that the authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager()  in the AuthServerConfiguration is not the same as that of the WebSecurityConfiguration?